# Mysql Select and count rows with multiple same values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query that allows me to select the data like shown below

```
id  Counter_Type Champion_Name Counter_Lane 
---|------------|------------|--------------
1  | 1          | Ahri       | 1
2  | 1          | Ahri       | 2
5  | 1          | Ahri       | 2
3  | 1          | Ahri       | 3
4  | 1          | Ahri       | 2
6  | 1          | Teemo      | 1
7  | 1          | Warwick    | 4
8  | 1          | Warwick    | 4
```

It should count the Counter_Lane and then the Counter_Type with the most should be shown for that name as shown below how it should show the data:

```
id  Counter_Type Champion_Name Counter_Lane 
---|------------|------------|--------------
1  | 1          | Ahri       | 2
2  | 1          | Teemo      | 1
3  | 1          | Warwick    | 4
```

I have tried the following code and its the closest I have came for over 3 hours now, so could someone help please.

```
SELECT 
    a.Counter_Type, Champion_For, a.Counter_Lane, a.Champion_Name, COUNT(*) as Amount, sum(vote_type = 'up') as Upvotes, sum(vote_type = 'down') as Downvotes, sum(vote_type = 'up')-sum(vote_type = 'down') as Totalvotes 
FROM Champion_Counters_Data a 
JOIN ( SELECT c.Counter_Lane, c.Champion_Name, COUNT(*) magnitude 
FROM Champion_Counters_Data c 
WHERE 
    Champion_For = "Aatrox" AND Counter_Type = 1 GROUP BY Champion_Name, Counter_Lane ORDER BY magnitude) b ON a.Champion_Name = b.Champion_Name AND b.Counter_Lane = a.Counter_Lane 
GROUP BY Champion_Name
```

Comment: your query seems overly complicated, the answer by Bishwas should give you the output you require, but I haven't checked it myself

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table  GROUP BY MAX(Counter_Lane)
```

This query is based on the output you want from the table you have given.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following SQL statement:**

```
SELECT Counter_Type , Champion_Name, MAX(Counter_Lane) 'Counter_Lane'
FROM(
    SELECT Counter_Type , Champion_Name , Counter_Lane
    FROM Champion_Counters_Data 
    GROUP BY Counter_Type , Champion_Name 
    HAVING COUNT(Counter_Lane) >= 2
) tb
GROUP BY Counter_Type , Champion_Name
```

Comment: Hello, that groups them, but the aim is to group them and get the highest Counter lane if it exists twice for a champion

Comment: @AaronBailey, I updated the answer as your comment. Let's check it

Answer (score 0):

You will need many subqueries as MySQL doesn't allow windows function or CTE.

<kbd>**[`Rextester Demo`](http://rextester.com/FBVWOM30679)**</kbd>

```
SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 as id,
t3.* 
from 
    (select t1.*
    FROM
      (SELECT counter_type,
              champion_name,
              counter_lane,
              count(*) AS cnt
       FROM table53
       GROUP BY champion_name,
                counter_lane
      ) t1
    INNER JOIN
      (SELECT counter_type,
              champion_name,
              max(cnt) AS mcnt
       FROM
            (SELECT counter_type,
                 champion_name,
                 counter_lane,
                 count(*) AS cnt
          FROM table53
          GROUP BY champion_name,
                   counter_lane
            ) t
       GROUP BY counter_type,
                champion_name
       ) t2 
    ON t1.counter_type=t2.counter_type
    AND t1.champion_name=t2.champion_name
    AND t1.cnt=t2.mcnt
    ) t3
,(SELECT @rn := 0) t
;
```

Output

```
+-----+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----+
|  id | counter_type | champion_name | counter_lane | cnt |
+-----+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----+
|   1 |            1 | Ahri          |            2 |   3 |
|   2 |            1 | Teemo         |            1 |   1 |
|   3 |            1 | Warwick       |            4 |   2 |
+-----+--------------+---------------+--------------+-----+
```

Idea is to first group by `champion_name` and `counter_lane` and get the `count` . So for `Ahri` you will get `cnt` as `3`. Now use another subquery to get corresponding `counter_lane`, which will be `2` for `Ahri`. At last, use a sequence number to generate id as `1`,`2`,`3` etc.

Comment: Hello, if there is 2 results with same value it shows that value is there a way to only show the top value always